# SQL Server CE Database Larger than Max Size - How can I regain access to this file to delete old data, compact and shrink the file?

Tags: sql-server-ce

I have a large SQL Server CE `.sdf` file with lots of historical data in it. Recently, the file hit the max file size limit for both my connection string and SQL Server CE.

I'm trying to use `SQLCECmd40.exe` to make a connection and delete data or shrink the file but each time I run a command, this message is shown.

```
SqlCeCmd40.exe -d "Data Source='Diagnostics.sdf';" -e compact
```

or

```
SqlCeCmd40.exe -d "Data Source='Diagnostics.sdf'; Max Database Size=4091;" -e compact
```

or

```
SqlCeCmd40.exe -d "Data Source='Diagnostics.sdf'; Max Database Size=4091;" -q "select top 10 Trace from Request order by Trace ;"
```

> Error Code: 80004005
> Message: The database file is larger than the configured maximum database size. This setting takes effect on the first concurrent database connection only.
> [ Required Max Database Size (in MB; 0 if unknown) = 4092 ]
> Minor Err.: 25104
> Source    : SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
> Num. Par. : 4092

Windows reports the file's size on disk as 3.99 GB (4,292,657,152 bytes).

How can I regain access to this file to delete old data, compact and shrink the file?

Comment: Make sure you have the very latest 4.0 version installed and try the compact command again

Comment: Maybe try shrink

Comment: I do have the very latest version 1.2.0.17 according to https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeCmd/releases.  The shrink command ran successfully but didn't modify the file's size.  Compact, like before, fails after running with low CPU usage for about 10 minutes.

Comment: I meant the very latest version ov the SQL Compact MSI. Look in the tools folder in the SQLCE repo

Comment: CE is way way out of date, you really should upgrade

Comment: It appears the version I've been running is 4.0.8876.1.  That matches the version I found on Github and the SP1 version I found on Microsoft.  https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/tree/master/tools/4.0.8902  Is that the correct version?  I ran the MSI, rebooted, and tried these commands again.  It produces the same result.